# What is the error in the following racket code?

Tags: racket, htdp

```
;creating traffic signal image 
(require 2htdp/image)

(define (bulb c)
  (circle 10 "solid" c))

(above (bulb "red")
       (bulb "yellow")
       (bulb "green"))
```

The Error Displayed is:. `Module Language: there can only be one expression in the definitions window in: (define (bulb c) (circle 10 "solid" c))`

Interactions disabled.
///I can't figure out the error

Comment: The part "creating traffic signal image" is commented out

Comment: It works for me... try changing the language

Answer (score 2):

DrRacket is failing to recognize the language being used in your code. You need to choose a language manually. It looks like you are following the first chapters of the HtDP textbook, so I recommend going for the Beginning Student Language. You can do so by:

- adding `#lang htdp/bsl` at the beginning of your file
- using the picker at the bottom of the DrRacket window:

[image: DrRacket language picker]

Comment: Thanks @Andrea Gottardo. Choosing a language.It helped